# Continuous but not d-continuous?

Tags: general-topology

A function $f:X\to Y$ is **d-supercontinuous** if for every open set $V\subset Y$ such that $f(x)\in V,$ $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open $F_{\sigma}$ set.

Obviously every d-supercontinuous is a continuous function but I am looking for an example where a function is continuous but not d-supercontinuous. So that the inverse image of any open set is open but not always $F_{\sigma}$. Of course in metric space both notions coincide so I know I need to look into non-metrizable spaces. I can't seem to understand what kind of spaces should I consider. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is " d-supercontinuous" the same as "d-continuous"? What is the role of $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is just to take any topological space $X$ such that not every open set is F<sub>σ</sub>, and consider the identity function $\mathrm{id}_X : X \to X$. This function is  clearly continuous, but if $V \subseteq X$ is an (nonempty) open set which is not F<sub>σ</sub>, then $V = \mathrm{id}_X^{-1} [ V ]$ is not an open F<sub>σ</sub>-set, so $\mathrm{id}_X$ cannot be d-continuous.

Examples of such spaces include:

1. The one-point compactification of an uncountable discrete space.
2. The lexicographically ordered unit square.
3. The closed ordinal space $[ 0 , \omega_1 ]$.
4. The long line.
5. The Stone–Čech compactification of the natural numbers.